# confusion with existential types in scala

Tags: scala, existential-type

I was struggling to understand existential types in scala but can't figure it out. Here is my test code:

```
scala> val a: Array[T] forSome {type T} = Array(1,2.2,"3")
a: Array[_] = Array(1, 2.2, 3)

scala> val b: Array[T forSome {type T}] = Array(1,2.2,"3")
b: Array[T forSome { type T }] = Array(1, 2.2, 3)

scala> a(0)
res35: Any = 1

scala> b(0)
res36: Any = 1

scala> a(0) = "x"
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String("x")
 required: T
              a(0) = "x"
                     ^

scala> b(0) = "x"
```

I was told that `Array[T] forSome {type T}` means any type of Array such as Array[Int], Array[String], etc. `Array[T forSome {type T}]` means Array[Any]. But according to the result of my test code, I can't see this difference, and the compile error message is also confusing. What does `required: T` means? I do appreciate if someone can give a detail explanation, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I was told that `Array[T] forSome {type T}` means any type of Array such as Array[Int], Array[String], etc.

That's correct. You might be surprised to see that the value `Array(1,2.2,"3")` is accepted as a value of type `Array[T] forSome {type T}`, even though `Array(1,2.2,"3")` is clearly not a value of type `Array[Int]` nor `Array[String]`. To understand what's going on, let's ask Scala what type it infers for `Array(1,2.2,"3")`:

```
scala> val x = Array(1,2.2,"3")
x: Array[Any] = Array(1, 2.2, 3)
```

Aha! So there is a type `T`, namely `Any`, so that `x` has type `Array[T]`. That's why `Array(1,2.2,"3")` is accepted as a value of type `Array[T] forSome {type T}`.

> `Array[T forSome {type T}]` means Array[Any]

Also correct. The type `<type expression involving T> forSome {type T}` is the supertype of all types in which `<type expression involving T>` is instantiated at a particular `T`. So `Array[T] forSome {type T}` is the supertype of `Array[Int]`, `Array[String]`, etc. And since `T forSome {type T}` is the supertype of `Int`, `String`, etc., `T forSome {type T}` is the supertype of all types, aka `Any`.

> ```
> scala> a(0)
> res35: Any = 1
> ```

You might be wondering why the result has type `Any`, not `T`. Compare with the following:

```
scala> (a(0), a(1))
res0: (T, T) forSome { type T } = (1,2.2)
```

As you can see, the type of the elements of `Array[T]` is indeed `T`. It's just that when we only fetch a single element from the array, it's type is `T forSome { type T }`, which simplifies to `Any`.

> ```
> scala> b(0)
> res36: Any = 1
> ```

This time the type `Any` is very much expected, since the type of the elements of `Array[T forSome {type T}]` is `T forSome {type T}`, aka `Any`.

Note that since the `forSome` is inside the brackets, the type for a pair of elements...

```
scala>  (b(0), b(1))
res1: (Any, Any) = (1,2.2)
```

...is `(T forSome {type T}, T forSome {type T})`, aka `(Any, Any)`.

> ```
> scala> a(0) = "x"
> <console>:10: error: type mismatch;
>  found   : String("x")
>  required: T
>               a(0) = "x"
>                      ^
> ```

The type of the value you assign to an `Array[T]` must be a subtype of `T`. We know that the value `a` has its `T` instantiated to `Any`, but when type checking, it's not the value's real type which matters, it is its declared type. And is `String` a subtype of `T`? No, since `a` could be an `Array[Int]` and a `String` cannot be put into an `Array[Int]`.

> ```
> scala> b(0) = "x"
> scala> b
> res2: Array[T forSome { type T }] = Array(x, 2.2, 3)
> ```

The type of the value you assign to an `Array[T forSome {type T}]` must be a subtype of `T forSome {type T}` aka `Any`. Is `String` a subtype of `Any`? Yes, so the assignment succeeds.

One last thing about existentials: type inference works best when `T` only has to be instantiated once. Earlier we saw that `(a(0), a(1))` produced a pair of elements which both have the same (unknown) type. I was actually surprised that this worked. In the following very similar example, `a(0)` and `a(1)` are also supposed to have the same type, and so the assignment is supposed to succeed, but it doesn't.

```
scala> a(0) = a(1)
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (some other)T(in value a)
 required: T(in value a)
       a(0) = a(1)
               ^
```

To show Scala that such an assignment is type safe, we can wrap it in a function which works for any `Array[T]`:

```
scala> def modifyArray[T](arr: Array[T]) =
     |   arr(0) = arr(1)
modifyArray: [T](arr: Array[T])Unit
```

We can now perform the assignment by applying our function to `a`, and this time it does succeed.

```
scala> modifyArray(a)

scala> a
res3: Array[_] = Array(2.2, 2.2, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not the same as `Array[Any]`. `Array[T forSome { type T; }]` means that you don't care what type inside of `Array`. You can write generic methods over Array e.g.: `def swap(arr : Array[T forSome { type T; }]) = arr(0) = arr(1);`. But Array type stays known and all expressions is typechecked with respect to it.

Comment: This is wrong. It's `Array[T] forSome { type T }` which means that.